# what is the best way of check existing database before creating new database on android

Tags: android, database

I have created a database for my android app which contains static data and does not require update/delete functionality thus when the app starts, I want to check if the db exists and if not then execute my dbAdapter class. I know its a simple if statement but I was just wondering the most efficient way to query whether the db exists.

Comment: I think, It would be better if you check for number of records in db on start of your app. For that, Get the cursor by selecting all the data from db and call getCount() method on cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `openOrCreateDatabase`  method

```
public boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to run the dbadapter only once, i mean when the application is first installed 
i use sharedpreferences to insert data only once , simply use it this way :

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (isFirstTime()) {
// insert data 
 }

}



 private boolean isFirstTime()
 {
 SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
 boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
 if (!ranBefore) {
// first time
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
 editor.commit();
 }
 return !ranBefore;
  }
```